# Help identifying this blue part

Tags: part-identification

[image]

I have scanned through Bricklink and I cannot find this part. I can not determine what to even call it. It has LEGO on the stud tops. I am assuming it's from a old set that has been discontinued. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

[image] I used Google Images to identify it.

Comment: Please add a link to the relevant bricklink page

Comment: Thank you so much !!     I thought of Google image search at one point but then forgot about it.